# Iframe is blocked in HTML

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to embed a video in the HTML page, however, the iframe is being blocked. I am not an expert with HTML. I can insert the video through `object` Can you please suggest what could be the issue ?

```
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <button class="closeButton" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/15731659" frameborder="0" width="880" height="450"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code used for inserting the video.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for embed.

```
<embed src="helloworld.flv">
```

In case of embedding youtube video

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0SU8-HJtYYc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Don't try iframe, as it will load two pages at a same time. Which may cause slow execution.

Here is the w3schools link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed_src

Comment: why are you using adham pic ? :D